# How to show the tabs according to the logged in user role? (Omega subtheme)

Tags: 7, users, theming, routes

I´m using an Omega subtheme in a Drupal 7 installation.
I´ve set at the theme configuration, that Drupal should show the tabs (`$tabs`).

What I want is to show the tabs only to a specific role.
I try this snippet out, wich didn´t worked. **My guess is that it didn´t worked because I´ve told Drupal through the omega subtheme, to show the tabs. And the theme show them to everybody**.

If I uncheck "show tabs" variable, they won´t show up, no matter what I do at my template file.

If I uncheck the tabs but add them inside my page template file, whey won´t show up either.

I want to be able to show the tabs or not according to the logged in user role.
Here´s my snippet that doesn´t worked (at my page.tpl.php file):

```
<?php 
global $user;
if (!in_array('admin', array_values($user->roles))) {
print render($tabs);
  }
  else {}
?>
```

What should I do? Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Omega sub theme then there would be a template file for each of the regions defined by the Theme.

The content comes in the template called region--content.tpl.php

You should see the tab printed there. you can put your logic there.